# Why it always shows the error index is out of array bounds?

Tags: c#

I'm crafting an app in c#, here is a problem that stopped me. My database table has 7 columns and it takes 7 while running application. But in the line `SingleRow[c] = data[0].ToString();` 
it shows me an error telling me the index is out of bounds of array. Please suggest. My code is below.

```
public string[] RowOnly()
{
    string[] SingleRow = new string[] { };
    conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show(data.HasRows.ToString());
    int i = data.FieldCount;
    while (data.Read())
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
        {
            SingleRow[c] = data[0].ToString();
        }                           
    }
    conn.Close();
    return SingleRow;      
}
```

Comment: Are you sure data has rows?

Comment: Because your singleRow simply has no elements, so accessing `SingleRow[c]` will result in this error. You cannot add new elements to an existing array, you may use a list for this instead and convert it back to an array when you´re done.

Comment: @Steve not a relevant dupe, not even same language and this isn't using mapwingis

Comment: @weston reopened. I don't have time to search now, but there are thousands of these questions for the same basic misunderstanding. The OP should search a bit before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem thanks @Maximilian Ast

```
 public string[] RowOnly()
    {

        conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show(data.HasRows.ToString());
        int i = data.FieldCount;
        List<string> SingleRow = new List<string>();
       while (data.Read())
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
            {
                SingleRow.Add(data[c].ToString());
            }

        }
        conn.Close();
        return SingleRow.ToArray();

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string[] SingleRow = new string[] { };
```

Is creating an array of length `0`

Do this:

```
string[] SingleRow = new string[i];
```

(You'll have to move it to after the line that initializes `i`)

i.e:

```
int i = data.FieldCount;
string[] SingleRow = new string[i];
```

Tip: Only use `{}` when you want to initalize the collection:

e.g. `new string[]{"abc", "def"};`

Comment: if you want it more dynamically try to use an List:  `List<string> SingleRow = new List<string>()` and in the end `return SingleRow.ToArray()`.

You can add elements by using `SingleRow.Add(data[0].ToString())`

Comment: @PradeepSapkota did you move the line to after the line `int i = ...`?

Comment: I think I got it, you must not do this: `new string[i]{};` Do this: `new string[i];` **No {} brackets**

Comment: Otherwise you will get the error "A constant value is expected"